# CDI - get unproxied instance of bean

Tags: cdi, java-ee-6

I would like to get an unproxied instance of a bean so that another module won't break as it throws an exception indicating the object I'm passing to it isn't of the right type.

Is this possible, if so how?  I don't want to create a new instance of the object because it already has some state saved.  I am hoping there is a short and quick way for me to get the actual object from the proxied instance.

Comment: Could you share the exception produced by the other library?  It could be that you just need to use a pseudo scoped bean - `@Dependent` or `@Singleton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't in a none implementation specific way, and you shouldn't.

The only thing you can do is to use a scope that doesnt need proxies. The two common ones are @javax.enterprise.context.Dependent and @javax.inject.Singleton.

Depending on use case you might be able to wrap it in an @Dependent scope been.

Comment: Actually, you need to reorganize your class in a way, that default constructor does not initialize anything.

Comment: @temaleva how is that related to the question?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write a comment to the question, not to the answer. But it is related to the question. If he says, the Object has already some state saved, when he get the proxy, that mean he has something in default constructor, that initialized the state, don't he?

Comment: @temaleva The state is not necessarily from the constructor. Actually, if the state would be from constructor he could just create a new instance that has the same state. My assumption was that the bean is stateful (he called setters on it).